# How to remove percentage labels in a pie chart created using plot_ly in R

Tags: r, pie-chart, plotly

```
library(plotly)
ds <- data.frame(labels = c("A", "B", "C"), values = c(10, 40, 60))
plot_ly(ds, labels = labels, values = values, type = "pie") %>%
layout(title = "Basic Pie Chart using Plotly")
```

I want to remove the percentage labels getting displayed over the pie chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [R chart attribute reference](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#pie-textinfo) you have to set `textinfo` property to `none`.

```
plot_ly(ds, labels = labels, values = values, type = "pie", textinfo = "none")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
library(plotly)
ds <- data.frame(labels = c("A", "B", "C"), values = c(10, 40, 60))
plot_ly(ds, labels = labels, values = values, type = "pie", textinfo= "text", text="") %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Pie Chart using Plotly")
```

If you want to label you can fill information in text="".